# python filling an list with random amount [lb,ub]

Tags: python, list, random

I want to fill some list with size N with random variable between LB and UB in python 3.6.

Would you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this works, using [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
>>> import random
>>> N = 5 # count
>>> LB = 0 # lower bound
>>> UB = 10 # upper bound
>>> [random.randint(LB, UB) for _ in range(N)]
[6, 6, 5, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into either `random` or `numpy.random` (the second is better in my opinion, but requires numpy to be installed).

The specific function to use depends on which numbers you want, and how you want them to be distributed:
if you want uniformly distributed integers, you can use `random.randint(LB, UB)`. If you want floats, you can use `random.uniform(LB, UB)`. You can also have normally distributed numbers for example.

numpy's random makes it much easier, as it can return a list. e.g.:

```
numpy.random.randint(LB, UB, N)
```